# Convert Vector[String] to Dataframe in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-spark

I have this Vector[String]:

```
user_uid,score,value
255938,34096,8
259117,34599,10
253664,28891,7
```

how can I convert it to DataFrame?

I already tried this:

```
val dataInVectorRow = dataInVectorString
  .map(_.split("\\s+"))
  .map(x => Row.fromSeq(x))

val fileRdd: RDD[Row] = sparkSession.sparkContext
  .parallelize(dataInVectorRow)

val schema = StructType(Seq(
      StructField("col1", StringType),
      StructField("col2", StringType),
      StructField("col3", StringType)
    ))

val df_from_file = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(fileRdd, schema)

df_from_file
```

But it give me this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
val dataToWrite = getColNames(column_names) ++
  data.map(x => x._2.mkString(",") + "," + x._1)
val header = dataToWrite.head.split(",")
val datas = dataToWrite.tail
val rdd = sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(datas)
val rowRDD = rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(attributes => Row(attributes(0).toDouble, attributes(1).toDouble, attributes(2).toDouble, attributes(3).toDouble))
val schema = StructType(header.map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName, DoubleType, nullable = true)))
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)

df
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make `dataInVectorRow` a `Vector[Seq[String]]` in order to get `fileRdd: RDD[Seq[String]]`

Then with the default spark encoders this should work:

```scala
import sparkSession.implicits._

val df_from_file =
  fileRdd.toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import sparkSession.implicits._

dataInVectorString
 .map(_.split("\\s+"))
 .map(_.split(","))
 .toDf("user_id", "score", "value")
```

You can always convert a seq of seq[string] to a DataFrame with `.toDF("each", "column", "name")`

You will need to `import sparkSession.implicits._` first!